# Run Xcode to run in lower version of IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am beginner for Xcode. I have developed a project its is running fine in iPad and iPhone 6.0 Simulator. I change Device as Universal for supporting both iPad and iPhone. Also change Deployment Target as 5.1 for supporting my iPad(IOS 5.1.1). While now running with my device its occurs error as 'signal SIGABRT' error in line

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using somewhere in your project a framework that is not supported in iOS 5. Also there is practically no reason today to maintain support for devices running iOS 5 as iOS 5 usage has dropped to 3% and maybe less.

Another issue that may cause this is that one of your .xib files has Autolayout checkbox checked. Uncheck this to all xibs as autolayout is not supported in iOS 5.

Comment: Sir i am using CoreLocation and MapKit framework.Did it support for iOS 5